# patching st terminal (st-xresources-20180309-c5ba9c0.diff) returned with Hunk #4 FAILED at 1013

Tags: suckless-terminal

I am trying to patch st-terminal and an error [Hunk #4 FAILED at 1013.] returned, I dont know what does that error mean and no idea how to solve it or where do I need to look!

`patch -p1 < ~/Downloads/st-xresources-20180309-c5ba9c0.diff
patching file config.def.h
patching file x.c
Hunk #3 succeeded at 797 (offset 5 lines).
Hunk #4 FAILED at 1013.
Hunk #5 succeeded at 1884 (offset 6 lines).
Hunk #6 succeeded at 2010 with fuzz 1 (offset 6 lines).
1 out of 6 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file x.c.rej`

`cat x.c.rej
--- x.c
+++ x.c
@@ -1013,8 +1027,6 @@ xinit(int cols, int rows)
        pid_t thispid = getpid();
        XColor xmousefg, xmousebg;
-       if (!(xw.dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL)))
-               die("Can't open display\n");
        xw.scr = XDefaultScreen(xw.dpy);
        xw.vis = XDefaultVisual(xw.dpy, xw.scr);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message

```
Hunk #4 FAILED at 1013.
```

is reflected in the reject, which shows the line numbers it attempted to patch.  That chunk might apply in the current version around line 1006 of **`x.c`**, except that it's been confused by a blank line:

```
        XColor xmousefg, xmousebg;

        if (!(xw.dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL)))
```

or, showing line numbers (text editor):

```
   1000 xinit(int cols, int rows)
   1001 {
   1002         XGCValues gcvalues;
   1003         Cursor cursor;
   1004         Window parent;
   1005         pid_t thispid = getpid();
   1006         XColor xmousefg, xmousebg;
   1007
   1008         if (!(xw.dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL)))
   1009                 die("can't open display\n");
   1010         xw.scr = XDefaultScreen(xw.dpy);
   1011         xw.vis = XDefaultVisual(xw.dpy, xw.scr);
```

The reject's "-" in the first column indicates that it was trying to remove the lines.  You could just edit those out, assuming that the other changes to the file were correct (i.e., that initialization might be redundant, might not, depending on how up-to-date the patch file is).